# Как получить чиcла дней прошедших с N числа

Tags: php, дата

Нужно получить 6 чисел в формате `d.m.y, d.m.y , d.m.y` с какого то числа месяца, например:

надо получить 6 дней с 2.11.2015 должно выглядеть так `2.11.2015, 3.11.2015, 4.11.2015...8.11.2015`

но как правильно реализовать не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = strtotime('2.11.2015');
$total = $date + (86400 * 6);
for($i=$date;$i<=$total;$i += 86400){
echo date('d.m.Y',$i);
}
```